# String base64 decoded un-gziped from little-endian 4-byte int to java int

Tags: java, gzip, base64, endianness, tmx

I'm trying to implement TMX files in Android and I was hoping someone could help. Based on the [TMX guide](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/tiled/index.php?title=Examining_the_map_format), in order to get the GID's I have to

> first base64 decode the string, then gunzip the resulting data if the compression attribute is set to "gzip" as in the above example. Finally, you can read 4 bytes at a time for each GID from the beginning of the data stream until the end.

I think I've figured out the base64 decoding and 'gunzip' but the result from the code below is 27,0,0,0 repeating. I think the output is supposed to be

> (0,0) (1,0) (2,0) (3,0) (0,1) (1,1) (2,1) (3,1) (0,2) (1,2) (2,2) (3,2)

Thanks!

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
 String myString = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAO3NoREAMAgEsLedAfafE4+s6l0jolNJiif18tt/Fj8AAMC9ARtYg28AEAAA";

 byte[] decode = Base64.decodeBase64(myString);

 ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode); 
 GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream;

 int read;
 try
 {
      gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

      InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(gzipInputStream);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader, 4);

      while ( ( read = bufferedReader.read() ) != -1 )
      {
           System.out.println("read :" + read);
      }
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't use `Reader`s for anything but character data!*

Use a `DataInput` to read the integers. Decorate your `GZIPInputStream` with a [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) and use [`readInt`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt()).

If the ints are little-endian, you'll need to reverse the order of the bytes for the type. Java uses network byte order (big-endian). For integers, this can be done with [Integer.reverseBytes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes(int)).

You can print the hex values using:

```
System.out.format("%08x", (int) n);
```

---

How to read all `int` values from a stream of arbitrary length:

One mechanism would be to use the `available()` method which *estimates* the number of remaining bytes:

```
byte[] ints = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xFF,
               (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xFF};
ByteArrayInputStream array = new ByteArrayInputStream(ints);
DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(array);
while(data.available() > 0) {
  int reversed = Integer.reverseBytes(data.readInt());
  System.out.format("%08x%n", reversed);
}
```

In the general case, `available()` is not a reliable mechanism. But you can augment your stream with a buffer to check data availability:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] ints = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xFF,
                    (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xBB, (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0xFF};
    ByteArrayInputStream array = new ByteArrayInputStream(ints);
    BufferedInputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream(array);
    DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(buffer);
    while(hasData(data)) {
      int reversed = Integer.reverseBytes(data.readInt());
      System.out.format("%08x%n", reversed);
    }
  }

  public static boolean hasData(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    in.mark(1);
    try {
      return in.read() != -1;
    } finally {
      in.reset();
    }
  }
```

Comment: @Erik - the order of answers to questions is not fixed on StackOverflow, so "below" is not a meaningful reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String myString = "H4sIAAAAAAAAA+3X2QrCMBAF0OKbSwWrCC4vdV/+w///JKeQgWFIatJ0SfE+HJDGonfaTJI8y7IlORkLkotrZ3I0SjUux2zfCSX/h/7tX/T9/5jjQl7kalSfb4nk2JAJ2Y78eUzJjMwjcnAtQnHt2sixIgVZR+TgWtjca8a4dvy+viNyaE1ycC2kh+WaZqvdUDmeppYxQp5DV313KG3n2JE9OYw8R2m5rw+638WuHzw/mrzjMWS/81k/ZM6U5ofsdz7rh8yZ0vxw9VtX361yfkzOlOZHSC/Xa4NtDgw1PwAgDvdSre/eGot7aV1PHgPbWTW1/a5vDn1WTW1f4ptDn1Vd+5KUyf1IkdXvS1LmOqti7wEAAAAAAAAAAF37AlFWzCEQJwAA";

    byte[] decode = Base64.decodeBase64(myString);

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decode); 

    int read;
    try
    {
        GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);

        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(gzipInputStream);

        for ( int i = 0; i < decode.length; i++ )
        {
            read = dataInputStream.readInt();
            int rRead = Integer.reverseBytes(read);
            System.out.println("read :" + rRead);

        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: this still doesn't look right - the number of bytes in the compressed byte array doesn't bear any relation to the number of ints. See my updated answer about how to read from the stream.